# Custom model attribute Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I am retrieving user info:

```
 /**
 * User info
 * Retrieve the user info based on the Access Token
 *
 * @param Request $request
 */
public function user(Request $request)
{
    return $this->successResponse(request()->user(), 200);
}
```

I would like to add an attribute in the model, that is not in the db, and is attribute is just a costant value. How can I do?

I tried adding public variable ,'gravatar', to the user model but they are not retreived:

```
class User extends Authenticatable 
{
use Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

public $gravatar = "hi";

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token','id','created_at','updated_at',
];


public function ideas()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Idea::class);
}

}
```

Comment: What do you mean, the public variable is not retrieved? You should be able to access it through request()->user()->gravatar

Comment: return $this->successResponse(request()->user(), 200);

Comment: I have only the db fields returned in the above call

Comment: What are the contents of you successResponse method?

Comment: return response()->json($data, $code);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is to setup accessors in your Eloquent class. If you later want that when getting the model data, you set the `$appends` property in your class.

Set up an accessor by adding this to your class:

```
public function getFooAttribute() {
    return 'foobar';
}
```

You then access the attribute by using `$model->foo`. Change `Foo` in `getFooAttribute` to change the name of the attribute.

If you later want to access it when trying to get all attributes or when trying to jsonify it, you add this to the `$appends` property:

```
protected $appends = ['foo'];
```

It's explained in the docs at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json